# How to sort int** array pointing to the int* array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, int

I have 2 arrays

```
int n = 10;
int a[n];
int** t = new int*[n];
```

then I make that `i` element of `t` points to the `i` element of `a`
Then I want to sort only pointers in `t` array
Then I try to bublesort it but it goes wrong

```
do{
    for(int i = 0; i < n -1; i++){
        if(*t[i] > *t[i+1]){
            char* x = t[i];
            t[i] = t[i+1];
            t[i+1] = x;
        }
        n--;
    }
}while(n>1);
```

Comment: pointers in t are already sorted as i'th points to the i-th element in a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not going through the entire array if you decrement n within the for loop, try placing it outside of the for loop